# Showing that for any composite binary number $b > 1$, $bb$ is also composite.

Tags: prime-numbers, binary

Say $b$ is the binary form of a composite number $d > 1$, I want to prove that $bb$ (concatenation of $b$ with itself) is also a composite number.

My approach:

- Given a binary number $b$, $bb$ is obtained by a series of transformations picked from $2b, 2b + 1$ (since appending a 0 is equivalent to $2b$ and appending a 1 is equivalent to $2b + 1$)
- We can rule out all series of transformations whose last transformation is appending a $0$ because these are even numbers
- Are there *any* prime numbers of the form $2n + 1, n > 1$? Turns out there is (for $n=3$ and probably more). So that seems like a dead-end.

Comment: Is $bb$ divisible by $b$?

Comment: With the exception of $b=1$, I don't think you need to assume that $b$ is composite.

Comment: With one exception, _every_ prime number is of the form $p=2n+1$. because if not then $p=2n$, so $p=2$ or $p$ is composite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is the bit-length of $b$, $\overline{bb}=b(2^n+1)$. Since $d>1$, $n\ge2$ and $b>1$. Thus $\overline{bb}$ is composite.

Comment: Is $\bar{bb}$ is the same concatenation as $bb$ in the question?
Trying to understand the sequence of steps but I'm still missing the pieces. Could you explain further how $2^n + 1$ comes about?

Comment: @sprajagopal $\overline{bb}$ is the same; to get a feel of what I'm referring to consider $254254=1001×254$.